# Powershell Leading zeros are trimmed in array using Measure-Object cmdlet

Tags: arrays, powershell, max, min, powershell-cmdlet

When using Powershell to find out the maximum or minimum value in a string array, the leading zeros of the outcome string are trimmed. How to retain the zeros?

```
$arr = @("0001", "0002", "0003")
($arr | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerating the array is the fastest method:

```
$max = ''
foreach ($el in $arr) {
    if ($el -gt $max) {
        $max = $el
    }
}
$max
```

Or use [SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd412070.aspx) from .NET 4 framework ([built-in since Win 8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/)), it's 2 times faster than Measure-Object but two times slower than the manual enumeration above. Still might be useful if you plan to sort the data without duplicates quickly: it's faster than the built-in Sort-Object.

```
([Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]]$arr).max
```

Obviously, it'll allocate some memory for the array index, but not the actual data as it'll be reused from the existing array. If you're concerned about it, just force garbage collection with `[gc]::Collect()`

Comment: Didn't expect that simply finding out the max/min value has to take a manual loop in Powershell. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Uhm, no, see the other answer for the simple and short code. I just like my scripts being instantaneous when dealing with large amounts of data in the log files etc. so I've promoted manual enumeration as it's several times faster than Sort/Sort-Object cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arr = @("0001", "0002", "0003")
$arr | sort -Descending | select -First 1
```